# Sample variance and error using Monte Carlo

Tags: variance, monte-carlo

Asked to compute estimator for the following function,

$\theta = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}$

which can be solved by transforming the limits to 0 to 1 and solving the following expectation using Monte Carlo,

$$ E[1/U \space e^{-1(-1+1/U)^2}]$$

where $U$ is uniformly distributed

The estimator is
$$\hat\theta = \frac 1N \sum_0^n \frac 1U \space e^{-1(-1+1/U)^2}. $$

How do I go about computing the sample variance and then the error? Are there any formulas to choose the best $N$?

Comment: I've had a look at the expectation expression, and I fail to get it equal to $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \text{d}x$. Could you possibly demonstrate the working for that so that we can check it?

Comment: there is a typo in the question. Please look at the same question posted in Math StackExchange. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748328/computing-sample-variance-and-error-using-monte-carlo